# Outside Wall Water Damage Repair

Tags: code-compliance, frame, sill

I removed a masonry flower bed that was causing water to flow into garage during rains. The masonry was allowing water column to form against house siding. Upon removal of flower bed I found damage to be much more extensive than assumed. Siding and framing are rotted out - outside and inside images below. This is an outside wall so is load bearing. How can I repair rotted sections of column and do it correctly to code meet code?

My plan was to support the structure and jack it up slightly to take off weight. Cut 6 inches extra from all rotted sections and replace with pressure treated wood. Since I want to only replace bad portions of the framing what are rules for sistering wood to stay up to code?

Outside. (old brown paint was top of masonry flower bed)
[image]

Inside. Wood sill and vertical columns damaged.
[image]

Comment: The good news is that this is a really small section of wall, so it shouldn't be too heavy. The bad news is that you've got a lot of plumbing in the way you're going to have to work around. Younger me says "dig in, go for it!", older me says, "brace the checkbook and hire it out."

Comment: Planning to do it myself :)

Comment: I'm sure you are and more power to you! Younger me would have dug right in. Older me is slightly more hesitant to take on big work like that. Unfortunately, I don't have any advice for your on how to go about doing it, you'll have to wait a bit longer for someone else to chime in. But, it sounds like you're on the right track. Just plan on having some extra 2x4 on hand to use as a "scab" along side the joints to strengthen them. A direct end-to-end 2x4 joint isn't super strong, and you'll have a hard time cutting half-laps in the trippled up column of studs...